# Global Variables to text file

Tags: lua

I'm trying to loop through all the globals and save them to a text file but I unable to do since io.write won't automatically convert to string.  Just trying to figure out how I can do this with the simplest way possible.

```
for k,v in pairs(_G) do
    print("Global", k, "value", v)
    io.open("test.txt", "a")
    io.write("Global", k, "value", v, "\n")
end
```

Comment: Encase the entire thing in `tostring()`? I.e. `io.write(tostring("Global " .. k .. " value " .. v .. "\n"))`

Comment: You probably want to change `io.open` to `io.output` and move it outside the loop.

Comment: `io.write` does not automatically convert values to strings on purpose: that that are not converted are useless to be written to a file. The way `print` does is not useful to write to a file when the values are tables and functions. Yes, `io.write` could automatically convert booleans to strings...

Answer (score 0):

`io.open` opens a file and returns a file handle. You use that handle for writing. You only open the file once, and you have to close it afterwards. The code should look more like this:

```
f = assert (io.open ("test.txt", "a"))  -- open file

for k, v in pairs (_G) do
    f:write ("Global: ", tostring (k), " = value: ", tostring (v), "\n")
end

f:close () -- done with file
```

Note that your code appends to an existing file. You may not want that. If not, change "a" to "w".